# How to connect multiple Flask dev servers to one MongoDB instance?

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, database-connection, mongoengine

I'm building a website in the Python [Flask framework](http://flask.pocoo.org/) in which I connect to a MongoDB using the [MongoEngine ORM](http://mongoengine.org/). I've got a simple (Ubuntu 14.04) development server on which I try to run multiple instances of the website on different ports (dev-version on port 5000 and a beta-version on port 5010). The problem is that MongoDB doesn't seem to allow multiple Flask instances to connect to MongoDB. When I start one flask development-server it works fine. When I then start another one and try to load a page in the browser which gets images from the MongoDB instance I first get the following error (it works fine if only one Flask dev server is started):

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2290, in open
    % (filename if filename else fp))
IOError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7f09a50f2dd0>
```

and after a couple of those I get many of these:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongoengine/queryset/base.py", line 309, in first
    result = queryset[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongoengine/queryset/base.py", line 160, in __getitem__
    return queryset._document._from_son(queryset._cursor[key],
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 595, in __getitem__
    for doc in clone:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1076, in next
    if len(self.__data) or self._refresh():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1020, in _refresh
    self.__uuid_subtype))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 933, in __send_message
    res = client._send_message_with_response(message, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1198, in _send_message_with_response
    member = self.__ensure_member()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 798, in __ensure_member
    return future.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/thread_util.py", line 214, in result
    raise self._exception
AutoReconnect: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

The MongoDB log at `/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log` simply says this:

```
Tue Apr 28 12:06:12.976 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:52035 #1 (1 connection now open)
Tue Apr 28 12:06:13.471 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:52042 #2 (2 connections now open)
Tue Apr 28 12:06:29.643 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:52347 #3 (3 connections now open)
Tue Apr 28 12:06:30.237 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:52361 #4 (4 connections now open)
Tue Apr 28 12:06:30.238 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:52362 #5 (5 connections now open)
Tue Apr 28 12:06:30.238 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:52363 #6 (6 connections now open)
Tue Apr 28 12:06:30.274 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:52425 #7 (7 connections now open)
Tue Apr 28 12:06:37.861 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:52625 #8 (8 connections now open)
Tue Apr 28 12:06:38.465 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:52642 #9 (9 connections now open)
Tue Apr 28 12:06:52.198 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:52910 #10 (10 connections now open)
Tue Apr 28 12:06:52.200 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:52911 #11 (11 connections now open)
Tue Apr 28 12:06:52.201 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:52912 #12 (12 connections now open)
Tue Apr 28 12:06:52.201 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:52913 #13 (13 connections now open)
Tue Apr 28 12:06:52.201 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:52914 #14 (14 connections now open)
```

Although I don't understand why it makes so many connections for just two flask dev servers, it does seem to allow multiple connections.

So does anybody know why two Flask development servers is too much? Is this a problem with MongoDB, MongoEngine, [flask_mongoengine](https://flask-mongoengine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) or with the Flask development server? Does anybody know what's happening here and how I can solve it? All tips are welcome!

[EDIT]

Alright, I finally found that the problem lies in the usage of the [crop functionality](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/master/PIL/Image.py#L1007-L1028) of the [Python Pillow library](http://python-pillow.github.io/) which I use to crop images. I've simplified the code below to isolate the problem. If I comment out the line `im = im.crop((1, 1, 100, 100))` there's no problem; I can repeatedly run this code and refresh pages with no problem at all. When I use the code below however, I can still refresh and run this code several times, but when I start two Flask dev servers I start getting `Connection refused` errors from pymongo and I need to restart MongoDB to get it going again.

Does anybody have any idea why the usage of the Pillow crop functionality crashes MongoDB while using two dev servers on the same machine?

```
@app.route('/doc/<docId>')
def getDoc(docId):
    userDoc = UserDocument.objects(id=docId).first()
    im = Image.open(userDoc.file_)
    imageFormat = im.format
    im = im.crop((1, 1, 100, 100))  # <== THIS IS THE PROBLEM
    thumbFilename = '/tmp/' + str(userDoc.id) + '.' + imageFormat  # Create a filename with the id of the image.
    im.save(thumbFilename, im.format)  # Cache the resized image in /tmp
    thumbFile = open(thumbFilename, 'r')  # Open the file from cache
    return Response(thumbFile, mimetype=mimetypes.guess_type(thumbFilename)[0])
```

Comment: All MongoDB drivers I am aware off maintain a connection pool. Read, they open several connections in advance to have one ready when it is needed. This is done to reduce latency.

Comment: The first step is to isolate the problem. Can you query using mongoengine from two processes or does that just happen with Flask-MongoEngine?

Comment: @nathancahill - Good idea. I just queried successfully from two separate interactive python terminals using MongoEngine, which suggests that the problem is in Flask_MongoEngine, but I don't really know how to invoke Flask_MongoEngine without starting the Flask dev-server. Any ideas how to proceed from here?

Comment: A simple Flask app that only opens a session? Run in two processes?

Comment: @nathancahill - Okay, this is rather frustrating: as per your suggestion I created a new small flask app which only reads from that same mongoDB instance, but it doesn't produce the same error. I'm now slowly adding more and more elements of the code that produces the error; websockets, sqlite, emailing, plugins etc. But this will take me a while. I will come back to this thread within a couple days (but hopefully a lot quicker). Thanks for now!

Comment: @nathancahill - It took me some time, but I managed to isolate the problem to the crop functionality of the Python Pillow library. I've edited the question with more info. Would you have any idea what the problem could be? I suspect this is the fault of Pillow, not of Flask or MongoDB, but I'm still rather lost here..